# How to find String Length Without [str length]?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, cocoa, nsstring

How to find string length Without use length algorithm. Please any one suggest me. What type of algorithm used to find string length.

Already i know [str length];

Any other option is available or not? If available means tell me.

Thanks.

Comment: Why don't you want to use `[NSString length]`? There seems to be no logical reason not use it.

Comment: Aplle default function "length" used to find a string length. We all are know that method. Below solution is k. But what type of algorithm used there?

Comment: I still don't understand what and why you are asking this? What do you mean by what type of algorithm is used. And still you don't explain why you can not just use the `length` method. May be if you describe issue there will be a better answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I hope this helps you

```
NSString *foo = @"IDontWantToUseStringLength";
const wchar_t *str = (const wchar_t*)[foo cStringUsingEncoding:NSUTF16StringEncoding];
int len = 0;
while (str[len] != '\0') {
    len++;
}
```

Comment: I'm guessing that @KrishJacky is using `NSString` and not a C string.

Comment: @rckoenes I hope my edited answer solves the problem :)

Comment: Wrong! UTF8 encoding have variable chars length. Yours algorithm gives result >= then method 'length'. Better to use unicode encoding and `const wchar_t*` string to calculate string length.

Comment: What type of algorithm Here used.

Comment: @Cy-4AH I updated my answer accordingly it took time because i was searching the syntax.

Comment: @KrishJacky I think you are smart enough to derive Algorithm from this simple source code